# iPhone Coredata saving error

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm trying to create core data application.
Some times when trying to save data, i'm seeing following error:

Error: NSInvalidArgumentException, 
Reason: *** -_referenceData64 only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSTemporaryObjectID_default _referenceData64]!, 
Description: *** -_referenceData64 only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSTemporaryObjectID_default _referenceData64]!

I didn't understand why this error is coming and how to avoid it. Can some one help me please.

Comment: What does your model look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** The original answer below is technically correct but doesn't accurately describe the true source of the error. The runtime can't find the correct attribute but the reason it can't find it is because the entity exist in another managed object context. The OP probably never had a `_referenceData64` attribute for any of his entities.

See: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?TemporaryObjectIdsDoNotRespondToReferenceData

**Original Answer:**

<strike>You have a class that has an attribute _referenceData64. In the data model, that class is marked as "abstract'. Select the entity in data model editor and check the box below that says "abstract". If it is checked, then that is your problem.</strike>

An abstract entity is never instantiated. Unless is has a subclass, you can't actually set its attributes to any value. Abstract entities just exist to provide templates for subclasses.

Comment: That is not actually correct. _referenceData64 is a property on a hidden abstract root object used internally by CoreData, this error has nothing to do with what you have in your model. You will see it most often when you do something wrong (like forming cross MOC relationships), though I am also relatively convinced there are some internal CoreData threading bugs that can cause this in correctly written multithreaded code as well.

Comment: You appear to be correct. I've never hit this before but then I wouldn't unless I made a specific mistake. However, the basic concept of my answer is sound. The runtime is attempting to find and entity attribute that does not exist in that context. Apparently, that was good enough for the OP to track down the problem.

Comment: **Addendum:** Since Apple added [context concurrency type support](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType) for new contexts, this error can also be thrown as a result of race conditions introduced by using `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. This may then be solved by changing to `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`.

Comment: @Irfan: Sorry, the post is nearly 4 years old and the cocodev site no longer exist. I don't remember the issue after all this time.